# Import route feature crossroads problems

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

My application have problems with importing routes send by server (calculated by here route api).
If one of imported point is directly where 2 roads are crossed or there is bridge above then this route is imported incorrectly.
In example from my image below all of the imported points are on E40 road (A4). Directly in the pin area there is a bridge above A4 road and for some reason Here creates s route that forces me to turn in that road.
Is there any parameter for changing that behavior or other way of importing route?

I got 1k+ geo coordinates in a single imported route so normal router calculations wont work (128 points limit).

[image: Problematic coordinate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If point is directly where 2 roads are crossed or there is bridge then will be taken incorrect road - yes, this is limitation of HERE Route API v7 and Premium mSDK 3.x - Currently we can not promise that this limitation will be removed in the future. The new mSDK 3.19 will be available soon on first days of September 2021.

Already improved in Route API v8 please use this playground https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/ to check it.

Also you can use Fleet Telematics API to calculate route with route matching functionality (doc. on https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/index.html) there is no limitations of amount of points and also wasn't noticed in the crossroads problems. Try please on this example https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/rme_basic